# How to integrate Phabricator code review tool to JIRA

Tags: integration, jira, jira-plugin, phabricator

Is it possible to integrate Phabricator code review tool with JIRA issue tracking system. When someone see the JIRA issue that user should be able to see the code review details if there is a code commit related to relevant issue.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 8):

I've tried the same thing, by following the steps here: https://secure.phabricator.com/T5422

I managed to link a jira issue with a phabricator diff. The diff link will appear in Issue Links as 'Implemented in' on a jira issue and Phabricator will comment on the issue when you create a diff. Also, you'll have a link to the jira issues inside your Phabricator diff in the field 'JIRA Issues'.

I use jira7, on their cloud. The link above outlines the steps but, I'll summarize them here as well:

- open the auth app in Phabricator and add jira as an auth provider
- while adding jira as an auth provider, you should follow the steps there to add phabricator as an application link in jira
- go to you account settings in the 'External accounts' section and add your jira account there
- make sure the phabricator daemons are running
- when you create a diff now (I use arcanist CLI), you should see a new field called 'Jira Issues' where you should add your jira issues ids
- the diff should now appear on the jira issues and the jira issues on the phabricator diff

Answer (score 1):

There is no clear way to integrate those, and globally the whole Atlassian products are mostly (only) made to work with each other. I'm not discussing the quality here as I found Jira/Confluence to be a pretty cool stack.

So for code review your best show Crucible
https://www.atlassian.com/software/crucible/overview/